# I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" even though i never user forEach anywhere in the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make Privateroute in react using react-router-dom but somehow i keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`.

Below is the main where error is frequently occurring in app.js.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log('Rest of the props', { ...rest });
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        firebase.auth().currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/signin" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Components/Navbar/Header';
import Home from './Components/page/Home';
import Profile from './Components/page/Profile/';
import SignUp from './Components/page/SignUp/SignUp';
import Login from './Components/page/Login/Login';
import Features from './Components/page/Features/Features';
import firebase from './Firebase';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authUser: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      authUser
        ? this.setState({ authUser })
        : this.setState({ authUser: null });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Main authUser={this.state.authUser} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const Main = withRouter(({ location, authUser }) => (
  <Switch>
    <div>
      {location.pathname !== '/signup' && location.pathname !== '/login' && (
        <Header authUser={authUser} />
      )}
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
    </div>
  </Switch>
));

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log('Rest of the props', { ...rest });
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        firebase.auth().currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/signin" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: does the error stack trace help you find which part of your code is at fault

Comment: no man it doesn't help in anyway

Comment: any indication where this error occurs

Comment: @Bravo when using " ...rest " i get error

Comment: `...rest` is in 3 places - which causes the problem?

Comment: @Bravo  very first one